# Group on a column where another column don't match

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**Columns are**

```
Id int
Timestamp bignit --yyyyMMddhhmmss format
transId char(36) -- guid
type nvarchar(100)
UserId int
```

I want to find out all those rows for a `UserId` (Group BY) which has got more than one transactions (`transId` don't match) on the same time (`timestamp` matches) and `type in (select typename from typesTable where active =1)` and one more filter like the `type` one.

I tried grouping on userid and timestamp but couldn't understand how do I add the "don't match" condition for transId column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this after GROUP BY

```
HAVING MIN (transId) <> MAX(transId)
```

or

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT transId) > 1
```

This will restrict you to different `transId` values per `userID, timestamp` grouping